# How do keep signed in works

Tags: java, web-applications

I would like to know how the "Keep Signed In" works and how it is achieved. 
Suppose I have enabled keep signed in on an website. So if I open that web site even after restarting my machine then it will auto sign in.

How this can be achieved with java.

Comment: what kind of web framework do you use?

Comment: it stores a cookie in the browser of the client, so next time the client open the website it will check if cookie exists and sign in based in the info that was stored

Comment: This might be helpful - [Capture the User](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/user-session-filter.html).

Answer (score 2):

After signing in, you could create a unique string, place it in the database along with the user ID who signed in, then store it as a cookie on the browser. Next time the user visits the site, if he's not signed in, then read the value of the cookie and see if a user is present in the database with that value. If so, sign him in and continue.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, do u mean to use persistent cookies?